# Value not returned when Observable change

Tags: swift, mvvm, swift4, system.reactive

I have one `ViewController` with 3 `subviews` :

- username (TextField)
- password (TextField)
- login (Button)

Expected:

Login button should 'enabled' if 'username' dan 'password' field characters is greater than 0.

Actual:

Observables changed, button still disabled.

Code :

```
import UIKit
import RxSwif
import RxCocoa

struct LoginViewModel {

    let username = Variable<String>("")
    let password = Variable<String>("")

    var isValid : Observable<Bool>{
        return Observable.combineLatest(username.asObservable(), password.asObservable(),
            resultSelector:{ (un,pw) -> Bool in
                return un.count > 0 && pw.count > 0
            }
        )
    }
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tUsername : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tPassword : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bLogin : UIButton!

    var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.viewModel.username.asObservable().map({$0 }).bind(to: self.tUsername!.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        self.viewModel.password.asObservable().map({$0 }).bind(to: self.tPassword!.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        self.viewModel.isValid.map({$0}).bind(to: self.bLogin!.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done binding in wrong way try below code:

```
self.tUsername!.rx.text.map {$0 ?? ""}.bind(to: viewModel.username).disposed(by: disposeBag)
self.tPassword!.rx.text.map {$0 ?? ""}.bind(to: viewModel.password).disposed(by: disposeBag)

viewModel.isValid.bind(to: bLogin.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```